# Why is the interruptible version of down() not used in scull's poll system call?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver

According to the [scullpipe source code](https://github.com/martinezjavier/ldd3/blob/master/scull/pipe.c#L231), in the poll system call, `down()` is used instead of `down_interruptible()` like everywhere else in the file. Why is it important **not** to have the interruptible version?

Comment: This might make a good question for [kernel newbies](https://kernelnewbies.org/MailingList) mailing list, if you don't get an answer here.

Comment: `down_interruptible()` is used when it is required to leave the sleeping mode either by any Signal or when the semaphore is acquired. On the other hand `down()` is used only when it is required to leave the sleeping mode only after the semaphore is acquired and it should not get interrupted by any signal.
Please have a look at https://www.spinics.net/lists/newbies/msg22887.html
Now, in the source code as the function name has `poll()` in it then it should be clear that the function should not get interrupted from any signal.